# (SystemJS) XHR error @angular/commobundles/common.umd.js/http not found

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

I am making a simple http request in my application.

I am using [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) and updating all my angular packages to 4.3.4

This is my `package.json`

```
    {
      "name": "angular-quickstart",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc -p src/",
        "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
        "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
        "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
        "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
        "prestart": "npm run build",
        "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
        "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
        "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
        "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
        "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
        "pretest": "npm run build",
        "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
        "pretest:once": "npm run build",
        "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
        "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.3.4",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.3.4",
        "@angular/core": "4.3.4",
        "@angular/forms": "4.3.4",
        "@angular/http": "4.3.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.4",
        "@angular/platform-server": "4.3.4",
        "@angular/router": "4.3.4",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
        "systemjs": "0.19.40",
        "typescript": "2.4.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
        "typescript": "~2.1.0",
        "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
        "tslint": "^3.15.1",
        "lodash": "^4.16.4",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
        "karma": "^1.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~4.0.14",
        "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
        "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
      },
      "repository": {}
    }
```

Here is my `System.config.js`

```
    /**
     * System configuration for Angular samples
     * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
     */
    (function (global) {
      System.config({
        paths: {
          // paths serve as alias
          'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
          // our app is within the app folder
          'app': 'app',

          // angular bundles
          '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
          '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
          '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
          '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
          '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
          '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
          '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
          '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

          // other libraries
          'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
          'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
          app: {
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            meta: {
              './*.js': {
                loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
              }
            }
          },
          rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
    })(this);
```

The code works fine until i install `HttpClientModule`.

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';


    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],
      bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

After i add `HttpClientModule`, i get an error:

> Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js/http

I have been at it for quite a while and looked at quite a lot of questions like this but can't find an answer for my problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect you should add the following keys to your systemjs configuration:

```
 map: {
  ...
  '@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',
  'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js'
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/IRXL1vSX7hGXjBI0K43R?p=preview)**

`tslib` is required because `@angular/common/http` depends on it. https://github.com/angular/common-builds/blob/4.3.0/bundles/common-http.umd.js#L7

Comment: It worked. Did not think of this before, just thought it would already be in quickstart. And i don't know why, but i can't find it in angular guide or api documentation.

Comment: Hmm... I made the change and am still getting the same error. Do I have to reload the systemjs file?

Comment: I also getting the same error...If there is any solution please tell me

Answer (score 2):

You should add `map` in systemjs configuration `@angular/common/http`

```
'@angular/common/http': 'node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js'
```

Additionally  It requires `tslib`

```
'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js'
```

Comment: I add those in my system sonfig but error is not solved